# Don't Render a table unless certain condition is true

Tags: birt

I am running into grouping errors on my dataset and am looking to run a script on the beforeFactory such that if a certain value is null, it doesn't render the table+grouping at all.

I've found [a related posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695347/birt-reports-stop-hidden-queries-from-being-executed?newreg=71d0cb455ec3435a995a20d47dd44fa6), but don't think it fully addresses my use-case. Will preventing the table from rendering still produce the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Dropping a table in beforeFactory script prevents any related datasets from being executed, therefore it prevents errors due to these datasets. Except of course if these datasets are also bound to further report elements.

The link you mentionned *should* address your use case. Though you don't mention  how this "certain value" compared with null is computed: if it is computed from a report parameter or a context variable it is fine, otherwise it is probably wrong because "beforeFactory" is triggered before all datasets (therefore this script cannot use a value returned by a dataset...).

I hope it helps.